# Deleting leftovers from audio troubleshooting

Tags: package-management, sound

fairly new to Ubuntu and I've spent the last couple days working to get everything set up and running as smoothly as I can. I wasn't getting audio through my motherboard sound-card, and was following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) troubleshooting guide, which ended up solving my problems. However, I now have a bunch of programs that weren't there previously. My question is do I need them, and if not, how do I go about removing them?

They are as follows -

- Echomixer
- Envy24 Control
- HDAJackRetask
- HDSPConf
- HDSPMixer
- Rmedigicontrol

I hadn't used any of these during my audio troubleshooting, (only used Pavucontrol in the end) but figured I'd ask first.

I have also tried purging a few through terminal commands by their name, but would receive "Unable to locate package." Not sure what to do.

[image: Image for reference]

I'm on 18.04.1, if that's relevant.

Comment: `hdajackretask`, [for example](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=HDAJackRetask&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), comes from `alsa-tools-gui`, which is the package you would remove.